# Winform gridview, update data without any lag?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I have about 50 records in a gridview, i have set a timer that will update the grid every 5 seconds. The problem is that if your placing a cursor (hovering) on the grid you will notice an annoying lag as the information being updated.

At first i was using the Datasource property but then tried to just update the cell value and it got the same result.

So is there any way to update the cell value of a grid without an lag almost like in ASP.Net ?

Comment: When you say cursor, are you just hovering the mouse cursor?  Or do you mean you have a cell in edit mode with an insertion caret?

Comment: how are you updating the records, one at a time?

Comment: Please share you data update code.